# pdo's error with oracle

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

When I use PDO to connect to Oracle DBMS,I got this problem:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCIEnvNlsCreate: Check the character set is valid and
>   that PHP has access to Oracle libraries and NLS data
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:619).

I have added `ORACLE_HOME`,`NLS_LANG`,`PATH` to environment variables and php's config is right.

follows are my setting and configs:

[NLS_LANG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOEI8.png) [ORACLE_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzP7z.png) [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWlTx.png) [php-oci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVffG.png) [PDO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMOpS.png) [php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGRL.png)

After setting environment variables I used `set PATH=C:` in cmd and restarted cmd to take effect.

My platform is `Windows Server 2008` and I'm using a web development environment **`PHPStudy`** with `php7.0.12`.And I got `instantclient_12_2` from Oracle website  [Instant Client for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)(12.2.0.1.0)

Comment: Now I use `oci_client_version()` in php but I just get  `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by copy `oraociei12.dll` in `instantclient_12_2`  to `E:\phpStudy\PHPTutorial\php\php-7.0.12-nts`. What a magic！

Comment: This suggests you either have several Oracle client libraries installed or your third-party PHP distribution ignores system PATH.

Comment: But I can get environment variables using getenv() and I have only installed one Oracle client in my server.I'm puzzled.

Comment: Well, of course, setting up OCI8 always involves some amounts of magic anyway... xD